# Script becomes too big

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to optimize the code I have.

Here is an example of how I use it. If I need to increase the number of buttons on the main page from 3 to 4 I follow these steps:

1. In HTML I will add another button with onclick="one(4)".
2. In JS I will create another array called test4 and include some data there.
3. In function one I will add another if with number === 4.
4. In function demo1 I will add 3 more lines with if size === 10, size === 11 and size === 12.

Eventually, the file will become huge and the numbers will be very big too because I want to add a lot of buttons on the main page.

Can you please advise if there is a way to simplify the code?

Here is the snippet:

```js
let test1 = ["11", "12", "13"];
let test2 = ["21", "22", "23"];
let test3 = ["31", "32", "33"];


function one (number) {
if (number === 1) {
    document.getElementById("btn").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("spis").classList.add("hidden")
    document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {demo1(1)}; 
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {demo1(2)}; 
    document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function() {demo1(3)}; 
    }
if (number === 2) {
    document.getElementById("btn").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("spis").classList.add("hidden")
    document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {demo1(4)}; 
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {demo1(5)}; 
    document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function() {demo1(6)}; 
    }
if (number === 3) {
    document.getElementById("btn").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("spis").classList.add("hidden")
    document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function() {demo1(7)}; 
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function() {demo1(8)}; 
    document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function() {demo1(9)}; 
    }    
}


    
function demo1 (size) {
document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("hidden")
    if (size === 1) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test1[0];
    }
    if (size === 2) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test1[1];
    }
    if (size === 3) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test1[2];
    }
    if (size === 4) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test2[0];
    }
    if (size === 5) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test2[1];
    }
    if (size === 6) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test2[2];
    }
    if (size === 7) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test3[0];
    }
    if (size === 8) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test3[1];
    }
    if (size === 9) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test3[2];
    }    

}

function three () {
    document.getElementById("btn").classList.add("hidden")
    document.getElementById("spis").classList.remove("hidden")
    document.getElementById("demo").classList.add("hidden")
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "";
}
```

```css
.active {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
        <div class="hidden" id="btn">
        <button id="btn1">1</button>
        <button id="btn2">2</button>
        <button id="btn3">3</button>
        <button onclick="three()">Back</button>
        </div>
        <div id="spis"> 
        <div class="column">
        <button onclick="one(1)">1</button>
        <button onclick="one(2)">2</button>
        <button onclick="one(3)">3</button> 
        </div>
        </div>
        <p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I do not really see the use of your arrays (`test1`, `test2`, ...) yet both of your functions can be narrowed down to few lines. Just look for the common logic in all of them. Most can be solved using [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).

Comment: The text within those arrays is different. The idea is to click the same buttons on the second page and always receive another text even though the buttons will remain the same. 

I understand that with the experience you can probably see it, but I'm just struggling to see it on my own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of non-deep refactoring:

```js
const tests = {
  1: ["11", "12", "13"],
  2: ["21", "22", "23"],
  3: ["31", "32", "33"],
  4: ["41", "42", "43"],
};

const elements = {
   btn: document.getElementById("btn"),
   spis: document.getElementById("spis"),
   demo: document.getElementById("demo"),
   btnCol1: document.getElementById("btn1"),
   btnCol2: document.getElementById("btn2"),
   btnCol3: document.getElementById("btn3"),
}

const demo1 = (e, row) => {
  const col = e.dataset.col - 1;
  const result = tests[row][col];
  elements.demo.innerText = result;
}

function one(e) {
    elements.btn.classList.remove("hidden");
    elements.spis.classList.add("hidden");
    elements.demo.classList.remove("hidden");
    
    const row = e.dataset.row;
    elements.btnCol1.onclick = function() {demo1(this, row)}; 
    elements.btnCol2.onclick = function() {demo1(this, row)}; 
    elements.btnCol3.onclick = function() {demo1(this, row)};  
}

function three() {
    elements.btn.classList.add("hidden")
    elements.spis.classList.remove("hidden")
    elements.demo.classList.add("hidden")
    elements.demo.innerText = "";
}
```

```css
.active {
    display: block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden" id="btn">
  <button id="btn1" data-col="1">1</button>
  <button id="btn2" data-col="2">2</button>
  <button id="btn3" data-col="3">3</button>
  <button onclick="three()">Back</button>
</div>
<div id="spis">
  <div class="column">
    <button onclick="one(this)" data-row="1">1</button>
    <button onclick="one(this)" data-row="2">2</button>
    <button onclick="one(this)" data-row="3">3</button>
    <button onclick="one(this)" data-row="4">4</button>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would remove the if conditions first and move to switch cases because im my opinion its just not very good to maintain a code like that. also all those dom manipulations. i would move them to different functions and pass the changes as arguments this will make the code more clean and easy to maintain

because in a case if you change one class name you have to change all those dom manipulations i dont think that will be easy to maintain. and in my opinion that's not very good. practice.

here's the code i did some modifications for you.

```js
let test1 = ["11", "12", "13"];
let test2 = ["21", "22", "23"];
let test3 = ["31", "32", "33"];

function one(number) {
  switch (number) {
    case 1:
      hideThings();
      buttonFunctions(1, 2, 3);
      break;
    case 2:
      hideThings();
      buttonFunctions(4, 5, 6);
      break;
    case 3:
      hideThings();
      buttonFunctions(7, 8, 9);
      break;
    default:
      console.log("error");
      break;
  }
}

function demo1(size) {
  document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("hidden");

  switch (size) {
    case 1:
      ChangeDemoState(0);

      break;
    case 2:
      ChangeDemoState(1);

      break;
    case 3:
      ChangeDemoState(2);

      break;
    case 4:
      ChangeDemoState();

      break;
    // do the rest here
    default:
      console.log("error");
  }
}

const hideThings = () => {
  document.getElementById("btn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("spis").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("hidden");
};

const ChangeDemoState = (value) => {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = test3[value];
};

const buttonFunctions = (v1, v2, v3) => {
  document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = function () {
    demo1(v1);
  };
  document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = function () {
    demo1(v2);
  };
  document.getElementById("btn3").onclick = function () {
    demo1(v3);
  };
};

function three() {
  document.getElementById("btn").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("spis").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("demo").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "";
}
```